# How to create image with active areas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom

I have a simple png image with building and I need to create custom areas above the image, like in [this example](http://leningradskiy.ndv.ru/apartment.htm) and call in js, using the DOM. So, I can solve this problem, via div tags with position: absolute, but is this the correct way?

Comment: Ive made a somewhat similar thing you can check out here http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/gpavxm

Answer (score 0):

It is a correct way. However, you can use the same approach as in your example. They use svg object with one big .png image.